# Return PHP array to javascript - format

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

When the code below completed, the data returned is in an array but not anything I can reference correctly.

AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
   url: './FILE.php',
   type: 'post',
   data: {'action': 'allfolders'},
   success: function(data, status) {
        var folders = data;         
   },
   error: function(xhr, desc, err) {

   }
 }); // end ajax call
```

PHP:

```
//Fetching from your database table.
$query = "SELECT * FROM folders ORDER BY folderName";

$result = fetchRecords($query);
echo json_encode($result);
```

RESULTS Returned to ajax:

```
data = "[{"lat":"latval","lon":"longval","value":"25"}]"
```

Need: a standard array that can be used to populate a table or treeview.

Comment: That is a standard array. It has one element which, in this case, happens to be an object.

Comment: or try JSON.parse(data) before that

Comment: If you're returning the data as a JSON encoded array, why not just use jQuery to parse it?

Comment: Edit with the output of print_r($result);

Comment: @John - yes, it is an object.  It is referencing properly that needs to be answered.

Comment: @davidvelila - this seems correct.  However, it returns "undefined" in console on testing.  JSON.parse(data); - actually worked.  THANK YOU!!!!

Answer (score 0):

David VeLilla was correct with this.  Unfortunately, it won't let me select his answer as correct so I am posting here.

All of the code above works correctly.  To return a readable datasource, enclose data in a JSON.parse() ==> JSON.parse(data);

Change $.ajax data reference:

`var folders = data;` TO `var folders = JSON.parse(data);`

and reference with

```
data[0]['lat']
```